# Using Alt+G to move selected object to the center of the grid causes objects to be (seemingly) parented

Tags: transforms, shortcut, parent, navigation, proportional-editing

beginner here!
I'm using Blender 3.1
I am following Blender Guru's tutorial making donuts.

In his 3.0 tutorial part 6, there is a step to select the light source and use Alt+G to move it to the center of the grid.

This worked for me. No issue there.
But after doing so, the light is now seemingly parented to the donut I've been working on.

I'm attaching a video capture of the following steps. https://youtu.be/q0lTHL7YGpY

1. Select ight source and click Alt+G.
2. Light source is moved to center of grid, select Donut and move. Hard to see light moving with donut.
3. Undo move and then select light to move and sees the Donut moving with the light
4. Undo Alt+G operation and able to move the light individually again without donut moving with light.

Any help with this is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable Proportional Edit to Move Objects separately.

Proportional Edit can be searched easily here at BSE.  I will leave that task for you.

Proportional Edit can function in

Object Mode or Edit Mode.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Mystery solved.

Comment: A common situation.  If feel your question was answered you can mark the proposed answer as your selected answer.  You can also downvote  if you do not like the proposed answer.